# eBay API AddItem Ebay call returns error 314 'You cannot create Shop Buy It Now item listings' for StoresFixedPrice listing type

Tags: ebay-api

I have a problem with adding products through eBay API using `AddItem`, `GTC` as duration and `StoresFixedPrice` as listing type:

```
<ListingDuration>GTC</ListingDuration>
<ListingType>StoresFixedPrice</ListingType>
```

In reply I receive error 314:

> You cannot create Shop Buy It Now item listings. Only Shop owners can
>   create Shop Buy It Now listings.

However I am "Basic Shop" owner on eBay.

What could be the reason for that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that StoresFixedPrice is not longer available as Listing type value

> Please do not list item with Listing Type as 'StoresFixedPrice'. This
>   enumeration value should no longer be used in the Add/Revise/Relist
>   family of calls.

This value also dont present in list of possible values for listingtype in Call Reference